# How do I make this slideshow react to swiping on a mobile device?

Tags: reactjs, mobile, slideshow, swipe

I'm new to React / JS and I've made a slideshow that advances slides by clicking the dots underneath. I would like to add support for swiping on the slideshow on the mobile device because the dots are too small. I've seen some tutorials for this, but they don't seem to play nice with the one I used to make the slideshow. Is this possible using my current setup? How is the most straightforward way to go about this?

```
    import React from 'react';
import './Slideshow.css';
import rmsm1 from './img/RMSMobile1.png';
import rmsm2 from './img/RMSMobile2.png';
import rmsm3 from './img/RMSMobile3.png';




const Slides = [rmsm1, rmsm2, rmsm3];
const delay = 15000;

function RMSMobileSlideshow() {

  const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);
  const timeoutRef = React.useRef(null);
  function resetTimeout() {
    if (timeoutRef.current) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current);
    }
  }
  React.useEffect(() => {resetTimeout();
    timeoutRef.current = setTimeout(
      () =>
        setIndex((prevIndex) =>
          prevIndex === Slides.length - 1 ? 0 : prevIndex + 1
        ),
      delay
    );

    return () => {resetTimeout();};
  }, [index]);

    return (
      <div className="slideshow">
        <div className="slideshowSlider"
        style={{ transform: `translate3d(${-index * 100}%, 0, 0)` }} >
          {Slides.map((imageSource, index) => (
           <img 
            className="slide" 
            key={index} 
            src={imageSource}
            alt="Slide"
            />
          ))}
        </div>



        <div className="slideshowDots">
        {Slides.map((_, idx) => (
          <div key={idx} className={`slideshowDot${index === idx ? " active" : ""}`} onClick={() => {
            setIndex(idx);
          }}></div>
        ))}
      </div>




      </div>
      
    );
  }

  export default RMSMobileSlideshow;
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this- I added this code here:

```
import './Slideshow.css';
import rmsm1 from './img/RMSMobile1.png';
import rmsm2 from './img/RMSMobile2.png';
import rmsm3 from './img/RMSMobile3.png';
import { useState } from "react";



const Slides = [rmsm1, rmsm2, rmsm3];
const delay = 15000;


function RMSMobileSlideshow() {


  const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);
  const timeoutRef = React.useRef(null);
```

*New code starts here:*

```
  const [touchPosition, setTouchPosition] = useState(null)

  const handleTouchStart = (e) => {
      const touchDown = e.touches[0].clientX
      setTouchPosition(touchDown)
  }
  
  const handleTouchMove = (e) => {
    const touchDown = touchPosition
  
    if(touchDown === null) {
        return
    }
  
    const currentTouch = e.touches[0].clientX
    const diff = touchDown - currentTouch
  
    if (diff > 5) {
      setIndex((prevIndex) =>
      prevIndex === Slides.length - 1 ? 0 : prevIndex + 1
    )
    }
  
    if (diff < -5) {
      setIndex((prevIndex) =>
      prevIndex === Slides.length - 1 ? 0 : prevIndex - 1
    )
    }
  
    setTouchPosition(null)
  }
```

*And then I added `onTouchStart={handleTouchStart} onTouchMove={handleTouchMove}` to the main container like so:*

```
  function resetTimeout() {
    if (timeoutRef.current) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current);
    }
  }
  React.useEffect(() => {resetTimeout();
    timeoutRef.current = setTimeout(
      () =>
        setIndex((prevIndex) =>
          prevIndex === Slides.length - 1 ? 0 : prevIndex + 1
        ),
      delay
    );

    return () => {resetTimeout();};
  }, [index]);

    return (
      <div className="slideshow" onTouchStart={handleTouchStart} onTouchMove={handleTouchMove}>
        <div className="slideshowSlider"
        style={{ transform: `translate3d(${-index * 100}%, 0, 0)` }} >
          {Slides.map((imageSource, index) => (
           <img 
            className="slide" 
            key={index} 
            src={imageSource}
            alt="Slide"
            />
          ))}
        </div>



        <div className="slideshowDots">
        {Slides.map((_, idx) => (
          <div key={idx} className={`slideshowDot${index === idx ? " active" : ""}`} onClick={() => {
            setIndex(idx);
          }}></div>
        ))}
      </div>




      </div>
      
    );
  }

  export default RMSMobileSlideshow;
```